# Is there any equivalent feature to InputFilter of TextView from XML in Jetpack compoes?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

How can I limit the size of input of TextField? in XML I used InputFilter
something like this:

```
val limitSizeInputFilter = arrayOf<InputFilter>(ByteLengthFilter(100, "UTF-8"))

binding.nsetName.filters = limitSizeInputFilter
```

Is there any equivalent to it in compose?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67846021/jetpack-compose-equivalent-to-inputfilter) but this restrict to regex which is depends on characters. And I need to check the byte length.

Comment: `inputString.toByteArray(charset("UTF-8")).size` will give the length of string correct ?

Comment: Yeah, I thought there might be simpler solution. But I just counted all the bytes and then added condition in the onValueChange.

Comment: Thats all the solution, you already able to find it, thats why i didnt post :)

Answer (score 0):

on `TextField` has the method `onValueChange`. You can here put any condition to filter input value. Even you can use as inputFilter for symbols with regex and so on.

Your question sulition here:

```
var text by remember {
    mutableStateOf("")
}

NTextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = {
        if (it.length < 100){
            text = it
        }
    },
)
```

Comment: length is different from byte though. It seemed like there's no filter in compose, So, just converted String to UTF-8 byte and added if condition as you did.

Comment: @c-an indeed...